# Create TransientRepository from oak segmentstore

Tags: jackrabbit-oak

I have an old file based Apache Jackrabbit repository which I have converted to Apache Oak repo using the oak-migrate utility. The old code is using 
    org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository class to deal with the repository and in new code I am getting the javax.jcr.Repository object for the Oak repo using  below code

> ```
> FileStore fs = FileStoreBuilder.fileStoreBuilder(new File(path)).build();      
> SegmentNodeStore ns = SegmentNodeStoreBuilders.builder(fs).build();  
> Repository repo = new Jcr(new Oak(ns)).createRepository();
> ```

How can I convert this javax.jcr.Repository  to org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository ? because there are so many places which use TransientRepository class

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's a completely different implementation.